# ionic 2 - Error Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio

Tags: cordova, ionic2, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I create ionic 2 project and add diagnostic cordova plugin like this :

```
ionic plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic

npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic
```

and add android platform like this :

```
ionic platform add android@latest
```

but when build with `ionic build android` console give me this error :

```
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

and I try to download manualy gradle.3.3-all.zip and change this  distributionUrl var in platform/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js

```
 var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'
```

to:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'file:///E:/gradles/gradle-3.3-all.zip';
```

but not working and console give me last error.

I dont know how to add gradle for android@latest version

Comment: Do you have android sdk properly installed?

Comment: yes ,this problem solve with define gradle in path system variable , but when run build android ,console give me :"You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components" error

Comment: You have to install the proper sdk version (via android sdk manager) and accept the terms. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-component/69570

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: yes ,I download gradle.zip manually and  include it into  path.

Comment: Similar issue try this -> [Window, Linux & MacOS users - Install Gradle manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413485/install-gradle-for-using-in-cordova-build-android/45853789#45853789)

Comment: You will also get this error if you are on Windows and your project path has parenthesis in it. eg. "cordova(something)". (At least until [this issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/824) is fixed.)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try installing gradle and include it into your path. Click the link below to get manual.
https://gradle.org/install

Comment: Thanks! Rediculous that cordova / ionic still hasn't fixed this.

Comment: If you have Android studio and a project using gradle, you can find it for example like:

~/apps/android-studio$ find . -type f -name gradle

./gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle. Sorry for markup, it's the comment. So you could add that to your PATH variable but you will need to keep that version installed.

Comment: Yes, I found one, added to the path and it worked like a charm, thanks.

> export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MyUser/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/xxx/gradle-4.1/bin

Comment: don't forget to reboot your computer (windows)

Answer (score 280):

Life is too short to spend it on messing with paths, etc.

Since I had **Homebrew** [installed on the iMac](https://brew.sh), I just ran this command:

```
brew install gradle
```

The Ionic3 project started to build successfully.

Comment: `brew update && brew install gradle` -- otherwise gradle doesn't install if brew needs to update first.

Comment: Worked for me running Cordova CLI without Ionic.   Plus I didn't have to do the double line to get gradle to install as mentioned in Kit's comment.   Very happy - simple solution.   Thanks so much @AFD !!!!

Comment: @Kit brew auto updates when you run `brew install` nowadays

Comment: "Life is too short to spend it on messing with $complicated_topic" will be my new ace up my sleeve at a job interview.

Comment: thanks much.. gr8 help..very true that "life is too short to spend it on messing..."

Comment: I know have 3(?) versions of jdk and gradle on my machine....but it works now so... ok

Comment: But Android Studio already includes Gradle, so why isn't it recognised?

Answer (score 113):

Just install gradle on linux, Even if Android Studio is installed,

> sudo apt install gradle

Comment: If you are linux user e.g. ubuntu and you are try to run cordova run android command at that time this commad will help

Answer (score 109):

**For windows users**:

Download gradle binary from the link in the answer [Gradle Download](https://gradle.org/install)

Extract the zip file to 'C:\Gradle' or somewhere else

open Edit Environment variable dialog from start menu > Search

**Click 'New' under system variables** and add as below

Variable Name `GRADLE_HOME` Variable Value `C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.1`

Then choose `PATH` variable from system variable list

append the gradle path to variable value like this `C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.1\bin`

then press win Key+R type cmd then enter > in command terminal type **gradle -v**

if the setup is correct you will see the gradle installation details

Comment: can i have gradle download link

Comment: Gradle download from here: https://gradle.org/releases/

Answer (score 27):

I was already installed Android Studio and it's just need to add gradle PATH to ~/.bash_profile on my MacOSX Mojave.
Also if gradle is upgraded then path might need to update again.

Example .bash_profile :

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="~/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export GRADLE_PATH="~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/bin"
export ANDROID_STUDIO="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS"
export PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_PATH:$ANDROID_STUDIO"
```

When edited your .bash_profile then run a command below to read it again.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I was able to use this method to find my own gradle path and insert it. Thank you.

Comment: How did you find the gradle path? Android Studio is supposed to have installed gradle but it's not being found by `Cordova requirements`. Or is it just an adaptor that Android Studio installs for gradle?

Comment: I forgot it now. Did you find it in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/ ?

Comment: Adding `GRADLE_PATH` didn't solve for me.

Answer (score 18):

**For Windows you can try below solution**

Copy your `gradle-->bin` path and add it to `system environment variable path`.

*In my case gradle path is*

```
C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3\bin
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thank you - this seems to me a much better solution that installing yet another version of Gradle on your computer.

Comment: Don't forget to start a new session of CMD after adding to path

Comment: I guess this is pretty obvious but if you upgrade the Gradle in Android Studio then you're going to have to re-add the path.

Answer (score 14):

In Ubuntu, Installing latest version of `gradle` solved the issue for me.

Try these steps to install the latest version,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gradle
```

then build using,

`cordova build android` or `ionic cordova build android`

**Note:** If you install gradle from ubuntu repo, it will install the old version 1.4 and will not help, so `sudo apt-get install gradle` alone will not help most times, if you did not add the repo `ppa:cwchien/gradle` earlier

Answer (score 13):

There is a problem with cordova version 6.4.0 and android 6.2.1 .so,please try with below compatible versions

cordova version must be 6.4.0

> sudo npm install -g cordova@6.4.0

Install android in your project

> sudo cordova platform add android@6.1.2

```
 or
```

> sudo ionic platform add android@6.1.2

Comment: You really shouldn't run npm with sudo!

Comment: if your system ask permissions then you need to use sudo

Comment: If you set it up right, it doesn't need permissions. You download untrusted code that can execute automatically. This should not be done with elevated permissions! See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Simply paste this line `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}` before first command and remove `sudo`.

Answer (score 10):

```
brew install gradle
```

In short that will save time :) Ionic team please fix this

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I intalled gradle with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

And Ready.

Comment: Do you really need the first line on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Hello Joe, good question, in Ubuntu repositories the version is 3.4.1 but in repository ppa:cwchien/gradle the version is 5.0. Is not really necessary to use the first line, but is important to install the last version.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to install gradle explicitly just to address this issue, you can overcome this by following the workaround as mentioned below:

1. Look for `check_reqs.js` file under platforms\android\cordova\lib folder
2. Edit the else part of `androidStudioPath` variable null check in `get_gradle_wrapper` function as below:

**Existing code:**

> `else {
>           //OK, let's try to check for Gradle!
>           return forgivingWhichSync('gradle');
>       }`

**Modified code:**

> `else {
>           //OK, let's try to check for Gradle!
>           var sdkDir = process.env['ANDROID_HOME'];
>           return path.join(sdkDir, 'tools', 'templates', 'gradle', 'wrapper', 'gradlew');
>       }`

**NOTE:** This change needs to be done everytime when the android platform is removed and re-added

**UPDATE:** The above workaround will work fine till Cordova Android version 6.3.0. For Cordova Android 6.4.0 and above, Gradle needs to be installed as a standalone dependency. Please find [Cordova Android 6.4.0 release notes](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/11/09/android-release.html) for more info on this.

Comment: Could someone let me know why this answer is downvoted?

Comment: it does not solve problem, install gradle and set path

Comment: @rashidnk have tried it in my cordova CLI and it works after this tweak. Could you explain what excatly you tried and what failed?

Comment: ok, but i dint downvote, i tried ur solution but it dint wrk, after installing gradle and setting path variable it worked

Comment: @rashidnk check this out where the answer is accpeted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra/44592751#44592751

Comment: This answer does solve the problem, but only for Cordova-Android plugin version below 6.3.0.

Comment: @TashPemhiwa You are absolutely right. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope CurrentUser
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
scoop install gradle
```

Answer (score 3):

Just install the Gradle through the command line
If you are using Mac try

```
brew install gradle
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add my two cents to this conversation. If you are a Windows user, you would like to take advantage of Chocolatey

Per https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gradle, you need to run
in your console (it assumes you already have Chocolatey installed).

```
choco install gradle
```

If you haven't installed Chocolatey, follow the instructions at https://chocolatey.org/install

Answer (score 2):

I am on Microsoft Windows:

I encountered this error after upgrading *Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0*. I solved it by changing the path to gradle in the PATH environment variable, which is now "**gradle-4.1**" for *Android Studio 3.0* (previously it was **"gradle-3.2" for Android Studio 2.3.3**)

Answer (score 2):

I moved **Android** folder path to another path and taked this error.

I resolved to this problem in below.

I was changed to **Gradle** path in system variables. But not path in user variables. You must change to path in system variables

[Screenshot this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGPm.png)

[Alternative Screenshot this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJw-g1S35GkYgNxUFjjQaruvaaPP0nja/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

First of all uninstall ionic and cordova, later set your variables envarionment `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` then reinstall ionic cordova and add platform like follow:

```
$ sudo npm install -g ionic cordova

$ ionic platform add android
```

The ionic will setup gradle packages properly.

Comment: My edit was rejected... so I post as a comment : the `npm` keyword is missing after `sudo` in the first line of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem

Download `gradle.zip` from this site https://gradle.org/install. And follow the instructions indicated in the site.

Then open another terminal cmd and execute the command:

```
Cordova build android --prod --release
End
```

Answer (score 1):

In Arch Linux/Manjaro:
sudo pacman -S gradle

Answer (score 0):

just install android studio and select your sdk folder as a android studio's sdk default folder and then android studio repair all the damage area and download needed files.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest gradle from https://gradle.org/install and set the gradle path upto bin in your PATH variable and export path in the directory you are working in

example : export PATH=/home/abc/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/abc/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/abc/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/abc/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/abc/Downloads/gradle-4.4.1/bin

I spent my whole day resolve this and ultimately this solution worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

If your gradle was working normally before and this came up (probably after you upgraded or reinstalled ionic or cordova - as was my case), you might want to leave the environment variable as is, and check if the folder listed there actually exists.

If it doesn't, rather than reinstalling gradle as mentioned above and changing the value of the environment variable, I had to recreate the old missing folder and copy the gradle files into them.

It seems the value of the gradle location is saved somewhere in Android Studio, and updating the `PATH` in system variables doesn't affect Android Studio checking for that same location after something triggers a change.