# Ionic Android can not build apk

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, apk, ionic3

[image]

I got gradle error when i try to build my project.Please help

following image describes my ionic info

[image]

Comment: install gradle.. https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: i have already android studio and gradle installed

Comment: yes may gradle version is mismatched

Comment: can you describe the procedure to solve this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android

Comment: this link suggest to include gradle to my path. can you please tell me that which path they talking about?. i have downloaded gradle zip file to please tell me where should i put this zip.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Gradle following this : https://gradle.org/install/
And to "include" your path, you have to add :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.0.1/bin
```

to the bash file of your pc :)  (the path of your /bin file that has been downloaded when installing gradle).

(did you try just a : sudo apt-get install gradle ? )