# Cordova Build Android failed exit code 1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2 and want to build an apk for my app to android then the error belows shows up. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I also had installed android studio and updated all the sdk requirements.

cordova build android - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
    ANDROID_HOME=/home/jayzdevera/Android/Sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
    Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android 
    Studio,
    or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
    in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Comment: The tslint error is just a warning that you import unused components. As the error says, you might need to update your cordova plugins

Comment: It worked! but theres another problem I'll edit it

Comment: Again as the error tells you, check if 'Gradle' is in your path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692039/3153169)

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry I am new to ionic and android studio

Comment: Just click on the link I provided in my comment and check from there

Comment: Okay thankyou so much!

Comment: It worked! Thankyou so much!