# How to create a SDK on android with ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, command-prompt

I am trying to create a SDK on android with ionic, when i try i write

> ionic cordova build android

but it does't work because when i search the SDK i don't find it, i don't know what to do, it is the first time that i use ionic and i don't know how to install the app on the phone,the app is ready to be used,to try the app i used the emulator with "ionic serve --lab" please help me

This is an image of what prompt does:
[image: This is an image of what prompt does]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of error messages are not as useful as text as images are not accessible, searchable, and are hard to view on phone sized screens. Please [edit] the question and include the text of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download gradle for building an android app. This answer is more proper as comment but I don't have enough reputations. So, I leave anwser.

Read the link below

[ionic 2 - Error Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android)

p.s. My original answer is a mistake.