# ionic gradle path issue

Tags: ionic-framework, gradle

I am novice to ionic, cordova and gradle. I am facing below issue when I am trying command `ionic cordova build android --release`

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Jindu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
(node:7964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
(node:7964) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the
future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried many solution provided like - one suggested to install gradle in sdk tools folder, set path of gradle in environment variables but all failed.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android

Comment: yes, I have added gradle path in environment variables. But still failed :(

Comment: As of now, I have solved the issue by installing Android Studio instead of just SDK tools.