# Cordova not found ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, android-sdk-2.3

Here is the error message 
[image]

I tried many solutions config path, reinstall SDK but none of them work, not found error still occurs
even if I already SDK path to environment

Here is the environment

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add gradle to your path. And make sure your restart your command prompt after changing path variable

Answer (score 0):

You have missed **set Graddle path**

please see this also

[ionic 2 - Error Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android)

First install gradle

https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: I already have a Gradle path set If you can see in a picture above