# Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin

I was installing android studio 3.5.1 after installing the latest one while trying to run my CORDOVA android application I got below Error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Software\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Kindly help out this problem I am new to Cordova app development

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692039/6875716

Comment: I had the same error. This helped https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/

Answer (score 3):

What is the output of the `gradle -v` command? To properly install Gradle you need to create/edit the `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` environment variable with the location of a Gradle distributable ZIP.

Check out [this guide to install Gradle](https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Same problem, but with Android Studio installed. What path do I have to fill in?