# Ionic Failed to find android_sdk_root, cannot build app on phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I prompt ionic cordova build android in vscode terminal, after a while it gives me:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

[Image of VSCode terminal][1]

I checked my paths and I think it's okay?

[Image of environment variables][2]

Can I get some help please?

I want to test my app on my phone. I already had my phone running on Xamarin.

EDIT(Adding verbose):

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
    at C:\Users\CGarcia\Documents\WorkersAppIONIC\ionic-form-ui\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:260:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 6708: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 6708 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "6708".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 6708 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +119ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 6708 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "6708".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 6708 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +3ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 8984: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 8984 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "8984".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 8984 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +7ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 8984 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: no se encontr� el proceso "8984".
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 8984 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +3ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +3ms
```

EDIT:
Now the error is different: (With verbose directly)

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (C:\Users\CGarcia\Documents\WorkersAppIONIC\ionic-form-ui\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:131:27)
    at ProjectBuilder.prepEnv (C:\Users\CGarcia\Documents\WorkersAppIONIC\ionic-form-ui\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\ProjectBuilder.js:262:27)        
    at Api.module.exports.run (C:\Users\CGarcia\Documents\WorkersAppIONIC\ionic-form-ui\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:168:20)
    at C:\Users\CGarcia\Documents\WorkersAppIONIC\ionic-form-ui\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:253:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I have Android Studio installed on this computer but never executed it on this user. Should I open it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO5wx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ4VE.png

Comment: Can you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools` to the Path variable. Then try the build command after restarting the terminal with `--verbose` flag.

Comment: I edited the question with the --verbose flag and changed both paths to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

Comment: What do you mean by "changed both paths to.." ?

Comment: I had ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME on C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk on my enviroment variables. See image. I changed those to what you wrote me.

Comment: Please keep the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME as per your android sdk path  (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`). Now add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools` to Path variable (by select Path and click Edit > New in the env variables)

Comment: Edited question with correct path (didn't understand in the first place, sorry).

Comment: Please check this for gradle installation - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58412874/2978985

Comment: Please check this for setting environment variables for Android(Ionic) - https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Akshaya Jeevan tips and [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android)