# How to solve ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) and ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Can someone show how to solve this issue associated with

ionic cordova build android

I have tried suggestions provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477221/android-sdk-root-undefined-recommended-setting-while-building-ionic-app-using) but the issue remain as it is.

> cordova.cmd build android
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
> Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log, it looks like either, you don't have Java installed or don't have it in your environment variable.
Ensure that `<path to java>/java/<jdk version>/bin` is in your environment variable. Follow this answer for adding it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241360/10602679

Android SDK is required to build Android apps. The recommended way to download it is through [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) else you need to download sdk [manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools)

Next, you need to add the Android sdk path in your Environment variable to access the command-line utility. Follow the screenshots provided in this answer for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900424/10602679

Answer (score 3):

To use cordova your need Java, Android SDK, and Gradle. If your take a peek at the source files, mainly `platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js` you can find the exact code that prints out the messages you get. Cordova checks environment variables you have set up on your system.

For Java, you need the JAVA_HOME variable, you can check variables by typing `echo $JAVA_HOME` on your terminal if you're using linux. If the variable does not get printed out, you have to set it manually. Install java 8 and in your terminal you can set it with `export JAVA_HOME="path_to_java"`. My path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`.

You need to do the same for ANDROID_HOME. When you install Android studio you will have the Android SDK installed. For me it's in my home directory `/home/username/Android/Sdk`.

For Gradle you don't need to set env variables. You can install it with `sudo apt install gradle`.

Note that once you close your terminal all the variables you added will disappear. You can make them permanent by adding the `export` commands to your `~/.profile` file and rebooting your system. You can alternatively type `source ~/.profile` in your terminal to load the variables into that terminal instance.

You may get an error about licences for Android. Just type `path_to_your_sdk/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` and accept all the licences.

If you have multiple Java versions installed Cordova may give you trouble since it doesn't only check the `JAVA_HOME` variable, even though it only need that location. If you're confident that your `JAVA_HOME` is set right, you can comment out lines 370-375 (the ones that throw an error when the following if statement is true `!String(values[0]).startsWith('1.8.')`) in the `platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js` and Cordova will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac

```
   unset JAVA_HOME


   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v "xx.xx.xx")
```