# How to solve Gradle or Android Studio installation error on an Ionic app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm trying to upgrade my Ionic Android APP with new functionalities but get an error

Run `$ ionic cordova build android --prod`

> cordova build android --release
> Generating initial manifest for Ionic Deploy...
> Ionic Deploy initial manifest successfully generated.
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/albertosanmartinmartinez/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/platform-tools/emulator/build-tools/29.0.0-rc2/zipalign (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/albertosanmartinmartinez/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
> Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
> or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
> in your path, or install Android Studio
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
> cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.

Run `$ brew info gradle`

> gradle: stable 6.8.1
> Open-source build automation tool based on the Groovy and Kotlin DSL
> https://www.gradle.org/
> Not installed
> From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gradle.rb
> License: Apache-2.0
> ==> Dependencies
> Required: openjdk ✘
> ==> Analytics
> install: 65,592 (30 days), 151,847 (90 days), 558,625 (365 days)
> install-on-request: 64,753 (30 days), 150,185 (90 days), 546,096 (365 days)
> build-error: 0 (30 days)

Reinstall `$ brew install gradle` and export it `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/gradle-7.0.2/bin`

And we rerun `$ ionic cordova build android --prod`hrow new error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 20.0.5594570
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> BUILD FAILED in 7s
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 38 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 36 up-to-date
> Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/.../platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/.../platforms/android/build.gradle

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `GRADLE_HOME` path

Comment: Updated with GRADLE_HOME path info

Comment: Check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android" Or "https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolve-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android-studio/"